# Regex to take urls

Tags: html, regex, perl

I have several web pages to parse, and there are links like

```
<a href="/news/monde/0,,3204267-VU5WX0lEIDUy,00.html" class="S48">Jean-Paul II opéré "avec succès" (24/02/2005)</a>

<a href="javascript:VerifCookie('4','/news/economie/0,,3204461-VU5WX0lEIDUy,00.html',700,600,52);" class="S48">Que peut-il se passer si le pape est incapable d'assurer sa tâche ? (24/02/2005)</a>
```

As you can see the second one has a leading JavaScript stuff and I want to get rid of it and also be compatible with the first type. So I wrote a regex in perl:

```
/<a href="[^\/]*?([^<']+?)[^"]*?" class="S48">([^<>]+?)<\/a>/
```

to catch the URL part without the javascript stuff and also the title part. But this regex takes only the title part for me, the url taken are just "/" or "j".

Any suggestion?

Comment: You should not use regex for this task. There surely if a HTML parser for perl. (Look at http://perl.active-venture.com/lib/HTML/Parser.html)

Comment: Do you want to catch /news/monde/0,,3204267-VU5WX0lEIDUy,00.html and /news/economie/0,,3204461-VU5WX0lEIDUy,00.html?

Comment: @FailedDev Yes that the url part i want

Comment: @Jens thanks i will give it a try but i still want to figure out why the regex doesn't work

Comment: The documentation link in the comments above is out of date by many years. Better: http://p3rl.org/HTML::Parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex :

```
!<a\s*href\s*=\s*".*?(/.*\.html).*"\s+class="S48">([^<>]+?)</a>!i
```

applied to your input produces these results for group 1 :

```
/news/monde/0,,3204267-VU5WX0lEIDUy,00.html
/news/economie/0,,3204461-VU5WX0lEIDUy,00.html
```

and these for group 2 :

```
Jean-Paul II opéré "avec succès" (24/02/2005)
Que peut-il se passer si le pape est incapable d'assurer sa tâche ? (24/02/2005)
```

Of course this works with your specific input. I would **strongly suggest** to avoid using regex to for .xml, .html, .xsl etc. There are far more better tools for this job.

Also much shorter version :

```
/.*?(\/.*\.html).*?>([^<]+)/i
```

Will produce same results.